# Links in css slideshow

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, slideshow

I would like to have the images in my slideshow to be clickable links, but just putting tags around it doesn't work:

```
<a href="#"><img class='photo'  src="Images/Red.jpeg" alt=""></a>
```

It probably has something to do with the animation, is there a way around this?

Css:

```
#slideshow {
  margin:50px auto;
  width:60em;
  height:18em;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:0.4em solid;
  border-color: black;
  position:relative;
}
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 16s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;
}
@keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 
@-webkit-keyframes round {
    25%{opacity:1;}
    40%{opacity:0;}
}

img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:12s;}
img:nth-child(4){-webkit-animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){-webkit-animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){-webkit-animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){-webkit-animation-delay:12s;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/Red.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/rose.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/White.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/rose.jpeg" alt="">      
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you make a demo please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap images with a and add class photo to a links. Remove class photo from images. Try that :)

Comment: It worked! Also had to change the img in the css to .photo:
img:nth-child(1){-webkit-animation-delay:12s;}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Wrap all images in `<a>` tags, each one with a "photolink" class or any name you want.

```
#slideshow a.photolink { display: block; }
```

Try changing "position: absolute" in .*photo* to "position: relative".